# seek bar UI problems(height) using XML

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, user-interface

I am working on the page where I am using seek bar, I designed a custom thumb and progress drawable in seek bar but progress bar height in not coming as I want, though it is coming as the same height as thumb, PFA

Seek bar:

```
   <SeekBar
            android:thumbOffset="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/milestone_text_view"
            android:id="@+id/custom_seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />
```

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" />
            <stroke android:width="0.2dp"
                android:color="@color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <size android:height="5dp" />
                <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
                <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_thumb.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/dark_teal" />
</shape>
```

reality
[image]
,
expected
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this way:

Seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
        android:thumbOffset="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/milestone_text_view"
        android:id="@+id/custom_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:max="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_seekbar"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" />
```

my_seekbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"/>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <stroke android:width="0.2dp"
                android:color="@color/black"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

seekbar_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            <size android:height="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

To disable seekbar touch:

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

or in Kotlin simply:

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->  true}
```

Comment: Your solution also works, "ARIGATOU"

Comment: TELL ME ONE MORE, how to fix its scrolling by hand, like no one can change the progress bar manually

Comment: Do you want seekbar to be disabled all the time or to be disabled due to some conditions?

Comment: i want my progress changes by incoming value only(stored in firbase) not manually by hand

Comment: Please check the answer. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem,

activity Code :-

```
 <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_range"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="500"
        android:maxHeight="8dp"
        android:minHeight="8dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ic_seekbar_bg"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_ellipse" />
```

ic_seekbar_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/black" />

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <solid android:color="@color/black" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

seekbar_ellipse.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="20dp"
        android:height="20dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#1ABCC1"/>

</shape>
```

Output :-

https://prnt.sc/mlafXHWj_rf3

Comment: I am NOT allowed to do vote up still, but  your solution works. "ARIGATOU"